# Is to possible convert a string from US-ASCII to UTF-8 encoding using groovy script?

Tags: groovy, utf-8, ascii

Content of the input file is read as string in my groovy script , data is in US-ASCII format , is it possible to set encoding of the string to UTF-8

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Any ASCII content is already UTF-8 content.

Comment: Data in file has some special characters (Ä,Ö) but in ASCII it is changed as ? .. we would need to encode with UTF-8 format for restoring the special charatcers

Comment: If it contains "Ä" and "Ö", then this isn't ASCII data.

Comment: The actual data has "Ä,Ö" , but when we retrieve data from data base as file its encoding changes to ASCII where these special characters are changed as "?"

Comment: That sounds quite different from what you wrote in the post. Maybe you should edit the question, giving a more accurate description of your problem and showing some code from your groovy script (or whichever code needs fixing).